# Pandas efficiently filter dynamic date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, sorting

I have a list of trips (50,000) that occurred over a certain time range and are tied to a particular device ID (150) and each has a trip ID.

I also have a list of gps co-ordinates (2,000,000) that occurred at a given time and are tied to a device ID. Some points will not be on a trip

My question is what is the fastest way to add the trip ID to all gps co-ordinates that occurred within that date range for the given device ID.

Here is my current solution. Right now is takes about 0.3 seconds per trip. I hear that for loops are bad with Pandas but I am not experienced enough with it to make anything else work.

Sample inputs:

Trip:

start, stop, device, trip_id

2021-08-24 15:50:27.063000+00:00, 2021-08-24 16:54:54+00:00, "B8", 1

Point:

dateTime, device, point_id

2020-04-23 19:50:28.063000+00:00,"B8", 1

```
df_trips.sort_values(by="device", inplace=True)
device = ""
points = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, trip in df_trips.iterrows():
    if device != trip['device']:
        device = trip['device']
        id_points = df_points[df_points['device'] == trip['device']]
    if trip['stop'] > trip['start']:
        trip_points = id_points[(id_points['dateTime'] > trip['start']) & (id_points['dateTime'] < trip['stop'])]
        trip_points['trip'] = trip['Unnamed: 0']
        points = points.append(trip_points)
    i += 1
print(len(points))
points.to_csv('TripPoints.csv')
print("Got Trips")
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you share some input of both dataframes?

Comment: I added a sample row of the csv file they come from, I unfortunately cannot show more of the data. If you know how to do filtering in Pandas with changing filter queries for each row that I what I think I need.

Comment: I recommend having a look at [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) without loop it may work assuming you can't have overlapping trips for the same device

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one can reproduce your data like this (please note for future questions how you can create dummy data to help your question to be answered faster).

```
df_trips = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2021-08-24 15:50:27.063000+00:00','2021-08-24 16:54:54+00:00', "B8", 1], 
    ['2021-08-28 15:50:27.063000+00:00','2021-08-30 16:54:54+00:00', "B8", 2], 
    ['2021-08-24 16:50:27.063000+00:00','2021-08-24 16:54:54+00:00', "A7", 3], 
], columns=['start', 'stop', 'device', 'trip_id'])
df_trips['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df_trips['start'])
df_trips['stop'] = pd.to_datetime(df_trips['stop'])
print(df_trips)
                             start                      stop device  trip_id
0 2021-08-24 15:50:27.063000+00:00 2021-08-24 16:54:54+00:00     B8        1
1 2021-08-28 15:50:27.063000+00:00 2021-08-30 16:54:54+00:00     B8        2
2 2021-08-24 16:50:27.063000+00:00 2021-08-24 16:54:54+00:00     A7        3
```

and

```
df_points = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2021-08-24 15:52:27.063000+00:00',"B8", 1],
    ['2021-08-25 15:50:27.063000+00:00',"B8", 2],
    ['2021-08-28 16:50:27.063000+00:00',"B8", 3],
    ['2021-08-29 15:50:27.063000+00:00',"B8", 4],
    ['2021-08-24 16:51:27.063000+00:00',"A7", 5],
], columns=['dateTime', 'device', 'point_id'])
df_points['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_points['dateTime'])
print(df_points)
                          dateTime device  point_id
0 2021-08-24 15:52:27.063000+00:00     B8         1 # in trip 1
1 2021-08-25 15:50:27.063000+00:00     B8         2 # no trip
2 2021-08-28 16:50:27.063000+00:00     B8         3 # trip 2
3 2021-08-29 15:50:27.063000+00:00     B8         4 # trip 2
4 2021-08-24 16:51:27.063000+00:00     A7         5 # trip 3, overlap time other device
```

So do you your job, use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) first by device, then look backward from the dateTime column to the previous start (same device)

```
points = pd.merge_asof(
    # sort both dataframe for  merging column mandatory
    df_points.sort_values('dateTime'), 
    df_trips.sort_values('start'), 
    # first merge by devce
    by='device', 
    # merge_asof on dateTime and start 
    left_on='dateTime',
    right_on='start', 
    # look for start before dateTime
    direction='backward'
)
print(points.sort_values('point_id'))
                          dateTime device  point_id  \
0 2021-08-24 15:52:27.063000+00:00     B8         1   
2 2021-08-25 15:50:27.063000+00:00     B8         2   
3 2021-08-28 16:50:27.063000+00:00     B8         3   
4 2021-08-29 15:50:27.063000+00:00     B8         4   
1 2021-08-24 16:51:27.063000+00:00     A7         5   

                             start                      stop  trip_id  
0 2021-08-24 15:50:27.063000+00:00 2021-08-24 16:54:54+00:00        1  
2 2021-08-24 15:50:27.063000+00:00 2021-08-24 16:54:54+00:00        1  
3 2021-08-28 15:50:27.063000+00:00 2021-08-30 16:54:54+00:00        2  
4 2021-08-28 15:50:27.063000+00:00 2021-08-30 16:54:54+00:00        2  
1 2021-08-24 16:50:27.063000+00:00 2021-08-24 16:54:54+00:00        3
```

Almost good, but you can see that the second row, dateTime is not between the start and stop, so either you replace trip_id by `pd.NA` or `None` (if string) when the dateTime is higher than stop for the trip found, or remove these kind of rows.

```
points.loc[points['dateTime']>points['stop'], 'trip_id'] = pd.NA
points = points[list(df_points.columns)+['trip_id']]
# or remove the rows without trip_id
#points = points.loc[points['dateTime']<=points['stop'], 
#                    list(df_points.columns)+['trip_id']]
print(points)
                          dateTime device  point_id trip_id
0 2021-08-24 15:52:27.063000+00:00     B8         1       1
1 2021-08-24 16:51:27.063000+00:00     A7         5       3
2 2021-08-25 15:50:27.063000+00:00     B8         2    <NA>
3 2021-08-28 16:50:27.063000+00:00     B8         3       2
4 2021-08-29 15:50:27.063000+00:00     B8         4       2
```